# JDA - Get Message ID of own Message

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I program a discord bot with JDA and my Question ist, how can I get the Id of a message my Bot sent ?

`channel.getLatestMessageIdLong()`only give me the ID of the latest Message, sent by a user

Comment: please provide your code for more understanding

Answer (score 1):

Use the queue callback on the MessageAction:

```java
channel.sendMessage(content).queue((message) -> {
    long messageId = message.getIdLong();
    // use messageId here
});
```

Keep in mind that `queue` is **async** which means that you **can't do something like this**:

```java
long[] messageId = new long[1];
channel.sendMessage(content).queue((message) -> {
    messageId[0] = message.getIdLong();
});
System.out.println(messageId[0]);
```

The callback you pass to `queue` will not run immediately. Any code that relies on the callback code should be inside the callback:

```java
channel.sendMessage(content).queue((message) -> {
    long messageId = message.getIdLong();
    System.out.println(messageId);
});
```

See also [Using RestAction](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/7%29-Using-RestAction)